# How to get an ID for an individual cell in a TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, uitableview

In my app I'm using a Web Service to populate my table view of jobs. When they click on a job, the app brings the user to the DetailsViewController which displays the job details. So far, I'm hardcoding the job ID to get the job details by doing the following:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];



NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:properUrlString];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

NSError *error;

NSMutableArray *jobsCallArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSString *currentId = @"usajobs:364160700";
for (NSDictionary *theJob in jobsCallArray)
{

  if([currentId isEqualToString:theJob[@"id"]])
  {
      jobTitle.text = theJob[@"position_title"];
      companyName.text = theJob[@"organization_name"];
      minimum.text = theJob[@"minimum"];
      maximum.text = theJob[@"maximum"];
  }



}


// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Now I would like for the "currentID" to equal the ID for each individual cell. How would I go about doing that?...

All help is appreciated,

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm following you, but here is what I understand of your question.
`How can I find back the currentID for the cell the User have selected ?`

There is 2 important method for UITableView
one in UITableViewDataSource
`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
the other in UITableViewDelegate
`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

You are probably keeping an Array of jobs that allow you to populate your TableViewCell in -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: using the indexPath to find the right index in your array.
Do the same logic in your -tableViewDidSelectRowAtIndexPath to get back the selected job.

---

You can ask the table view for the selected cell with this method :
`- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForSelectedRow`

Comment: I'm actually using the prepareForSegue to pass the data